# Restriction of $C^k$ function

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $f: V \rightarrow W $ a $C^k$ map from an open set $V\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n $ to an open set $W\subseteq\mathbb{R}$.

Suppose $x \in f(V)$ and let $I$ be an open neighbourhood of $x$ contained in $W$.

> Is it true that the restriction $g: f^{-1}(I) \rightarrow I$ **of $f$** is still $C^k$?

$g$ is obviously well defined, and I think that since $f^{-1}(V)$ is open then the $C^k$ property should be preserved.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy $f'$ is the restriction of $f$, not the derivative. Is it still true that we loose and order of derivability?

Comment: @postmortes $f'$ is not the derivative of $f$

Comment: The restriction of a $C^{k}$ map to any open subset of the domain  is  a $C^{k}$ function. Why do you even doubt that?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Because I didn't know that the restriction of a $C^k$ map to an open set of the domain is still $C^k$. Now I know it and it solves my problem.